# Increase the limit of 20 instagram api request

Tags: api, request, limit, instagram

I have a php script to follow the followers of famous person, this script uses instagram api to do this.
When the script runs, it follows few persons of the overall list of users. How can I increase the "20" limit of this request ?
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Instagram just changed their limits, I have a website: http://instapromobiz.com that can follow/unfollow 60 users an hour.

You must first disable implicit (client side) authentication and then enforce signed headers in your client manager. Then when making a request sign your headers. See here:
http://instagram.com/developer/restrict-api-requests/